# AngularJS / modal split plunker into controller / services

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I would like to know how can I split this angular js / modal sample into 2 controllers files and 1 service instead of one js file:

https://plnkr.co/edit/D48xcomnXdClccMnl5Jj?p=preview

```
 angularjs / modal
```

Comment: No need for saying thanks. You thank people by accepting the best answer and upvoting all good ones, including the best one ;)

Comment: That plunker doesn't even run for me and pukes errors all over the console.